# Changing the code of specific component doesn't trigger fast refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, refresh

I have a component hierarchy like this:

```
Dashboard -> inside it:
- Table -> inside it:
  - RowTable
```

The problem here is whenever I change the code of the `Dashboard` or the `table`, everything is working fine and the application is being refreshed, but whenever I change the component `RowTable` code, I can see the 'refresh' toast, but nothing is being refreshed, I need to reload the whole app to see the new changes.

I'm not sure, and I don't know if it's related, but I noticed this issue after initializing react native debugger in VS Code
I did assign a key to the whole `RowTable` but didn't fix the issue.